# structuring javascript/jquery in a site

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, structure

So I have this website where we have loads of `javascript`. basically they all run on top of `jQuery`. The site uses a `layout` and multiple `view` files. So the structure is roughly like this:

```
layout.php

loadHeader();
loadBody();
loadFooter();
```

`loadHeader()` will load all the required CSS
`loadFooter()` will load all the required JS

Now `loadBody()` loads different `PHP scripts`. Most of these scripts need `jQuery/Javascript` to work correctly. Right now everyone is adding all the required `jQuery` to a file named `site.js` which is loaded as the last `.js file` in `loadFooter()`

This has created a BIG monolithic code structure like:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
  //init this...

  //do that...

  //bind this...

  //ajax that...
});
```

This is growing unmanageable very quickly. In a structure like the one we have, I am not sure if the .js files can be loaded on-demand from the `loadBody()`, since the dependencies `(jQuery, bootstrap, plugins etc)` get loaded in the end. Also, does everything need to be wrapped inside `document.ready` like it is now?

Comment: There's no reason why you couldn't have multiple `document.ready` calls, breaking down your code into manageable blocks.

Comment: Have you considered using Javascript script loading framework such as RequireJS / HeadJS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> does everything need to be wrapped inside document.ready like it is now?

If it's only some calculation in the back-end then it doesn't matter if the document is ready or not.

If you need to manipulate or fetch something from the DOM then you need it to be ready.

> This has created a BIG monolithic code structure like:

The "init this do that ajax" can become quite big, like you're experimenting, but if some parts of it are suppose to server the same/similar purpose then you could put them into separate functions and to avoid a humongous file then you could add related code into separate files.

Other than that it's quite hard to avoid, just like any code. Just make sure related code is separated in unique functions and in separated files.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    init();
    doThat();
    bindThis();
    ajaxThat();
});
```

Is a fair separation, but perhaps you can simplify it even better.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    init();
    handleProcessInsertName();
});
```

Wherea you've defined the function properly (in the same file, or preferably, in another file).

```
function handleProcessInsertName()
{
    doThat();
    bindThis();
    ajaxThat();
}
```

Comment: Ah...I hear what you are saying, that make sense.

Comment: Yeah, this is actually quite cozy in comparison to the callback-hell which you've maybe encountered in node.js, if not, have fun when that time comes :P Anyway there's not much more to say, give the question some time if you want more answers but if not then feel free to close it by accepting the answer :) Good luck!

Answer (score -1):

There are many ways to refactor the code. What I often do is:

```
$(function() {
    setupMenu();
    setupFooter();
    initSelect2(); 
});
// and then...
var setupMenu = function() {}
var setupFooter = function() {}
var initSelect2 = function() {}
```